# Problem with my 02 Lincoln Ls

Tags: lincoln, cranks-wont-run

I got a 02 Lincoln LS that won't run. When I first got the car it would start up and run but I had to play with the gas pedal to get it past the stuttering and then it would go. Now it won't run. Some days it will start up and hold an idle but not go. I think the fuel pump is working. I pushed the fuel thing down under the hood and fuel came out of it. I don't know if the pump is working right or not. I just don't have the money to put it into the shop to find out the problem.

This is a nice car. I would hate to junk it over this I would like to fix it

Comment: Welcome to Mechanics.SE ... which engine is in the car? Have you had the codes read? You're right, the Lincoln LS is a great car. Based off the Jaguar S-type chassis. I really like them.

Comment: Check engine light?

Answer (score 2):

For crank no start issues with most fuel-injected cars (like your Lincoln) you need to troubleshoot around 3 main issues.

1. You need to verify you are getting spark and timing is correct.
2. You need to verify you are getting the correct amount of fuel.
3. You need to verify you are getting air into the engine.

You can rent tools for 1 and 2 from places like autozone.

---

A decent overview of basic diagnosis for crank issues/no start
Youtube, search "No Start, Diagnostic Basics - EricTheCarGuy", I would link but I have low rep. :)

---

That being said, assuming there isn't a check engine light or fault codes in your ecu on your Lincoln LS, the first things you should check are the Idle Air Control Valve and the Ignition Coils.

The idle air control valve is located on the throttle body.
Here is a related video that should help with locating it.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L57KEQwl9pU

The Ignition Coils are directly attached to the spark plugs.
Here is a video for someone replacing them on a 2005.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XgiDEkU6MX0

To find a procedure for testing them if you want to blindly avoid replacing them, you should buy/acquire a service manual for your car.

Answer (score 1):

The cause of a car running can be for example lack of spark, lack of fuel or lack of compression. Lack of compression generally means expensive engine damage. The cause in your case can be practically anything: for example, bad fuel injectors can cause the symptoms you're seeing. Weak spark can also cause the problems. Consider also vacuum leaks as the potential cause, as a vacuum leak can affect the air/fuel ratio.

Does this car have electronic throttle control? Judging from the year, it might not, as 2002 was around the time when car manufacturers were transitioning to electronic throttle control. If not, the cause can be a bad idle air control valve. This would explain why you got the car running  by playing with the gas pedal. The throttle valve allows enough air to get to the engine if you press the gas pedal. Without this, a bad idle air control valve might not let enough air into the engine. If the car has electronic throttle control, you will definitely get a warning light on the dashboard if the system is malfunctioning.

A bad sensor such as the crankshaft position sensor can also cause the issues you're seeing. If the sensor is just barely functioning, the car can run for a while but then stop.

I also had starting troubles with a car that had a failing ECU relay.

Without a check engine light, the diagnosis might be hard.